# Unable to connect to MySQL in Docker from local host (Docker for Mac beta)

Tags: mysql, docker, localhost

On Mac OS X El Capitan.

Used to use Docker Toolbox. Just removed that and installed Docker for Mac beta. (I think the removal and installation is clean.)

Essentially launching a MySQL server container like this:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -d mysql:5.7.13
```

(or mysql/mysql-server:5.7.13). The launch seems to be fine.Then I tried to connect to this server from Sequel Pro, via "Standard" way, host 127.0.0.1, root, 1234. Got

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.

Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Using `-p 3306:3306` did not help.

It used to work with Docker Toolbox where I launched by

```
    docker run \
      -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 \
      -d \
      --expose 3306 \
      -p 3306:3306 \
      mysql:5.7.12
```

and connected to host 192.168.99.100. That worked fine.

I suspect the Docker for Mac "migration" during installation (copying existing Docker stuff into the new VM) may keep some old data (from the old MySQL containers) that is causing issues, but don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not want to install a MySQL command-line client on the host machine, therefore I can't do `mysql -h...` to test things.

Comment: Did you set a port? You mentioned that with Docker Toolbox you were using -p to set port to 3306:3306. But you didn't included that in your command at the top. If that's not it I'd advise trying your machine's ip (from ifconfig) just in case...or localhost.

Comment: Note in the Toolbox installation, I launched with `--expose` and `-p`; on Sequel Pro I provided '192.168.99.100', '3306', 'root', '1234'. That worked fine.  In Docker for Mac, I did not use `--expose` and `-p`. Using `-p` gave me `docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint local-docker-mysql (d9816ec5bc57dfd29df475195f3ab7d5b52fc0527677f1e705eecc02ebdac973): Error starting userland proxy: Failed to bind tcp 0.0.0.0:3306 address already in use.` The official MySQL docker page examples do not use `-p`.

Comment: Do you have MySQL running on your Mac (which will be using port 3306)?

Comment: @techtabu yes. A pre-docker days installation of mysql server was lurking around on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've not configured access for root user from other hosts rather than default localhost.

Passing **-p 3306:3306** you just creating a port forwarding from host machine to guest one. So you can simply allow your user to connect to the DB from your host machine which is 172.17.0.1.

E.g. I'm using following dummy container startup script which changes root's password in case it won't changed before:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $(dirname $0)

docker-compose up -d

ROOT_PASSWORD=root
CONTAINER=____mysql_container_name___
CHANGE_PASS_SQL="delete from mysql.user;grant all on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by '${ROOT_PASSWORD}' with grant option;flush privileges;"
CHANGE_PASS="docker exec -it ${CONTAINER} mysql -s -uroot -e \"${CHANGE_PASS_SQL}\" 2>/dev/null"

WITH_PASS='echo "select now();" | docker exec -i ${CONTAINER} mysql -root -proot 1>&2 2>/dev/null'
NO_PASS='echo "select now();" | docker exec -i ${CONTAINER} mysql -root 1>&2 2>/dev/null'

WITH_PASS_EXIT_CODE=1000
NO_PASS_EXIT_CODE=1000

while [ ${WITH_PASS_EXIT_CODE} -gt 0 ];do
    eval "${WITH_PASS}"
    WITH_PASS_EXIT_CODE=$?
    eval "${NO_PASS}"
    NO_PASS_EXIT_CODE=$?

    echo -n .

    if [ ${NO_PASS_EXIT_CODE} -eq 0 ];then
        eval "${CHANGE_PASS}"
    else
        sleep 1
    fi
done

echo
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Solved. Turned out I had mysql running on my machine without my knowledge. It's installed before Docker. The ToolBox Docker did not conflict with localhost, hence the problem did not show. Cleaned out mysql, boot2docker, VirtualBox. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

use `--protocol=TCP` parameter if you want to connect to the MySQL running on docker.

example:

`mysql --protocol=TCP -uroot -p1234`

check [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-in-docker-from-local-host-docker-for-mac-beta/16987/2) link for more details.

Answer (score -1):

If the solution above doesn't help you, check if MySql is already started on your computer:

```
mysql.server status
```

If it **is** running, you can stop it by:

```
mysql.server stop
```

After that, rebuild the DB docker containers and everything should work fine :)